# Scala: Use case for Map.flatten?

Tags: scala, dictionary, flatten

The [documentation on Map.flatten](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map@flatten[B]:Map[B]) states the following:

> Converts this map of traversable collections into a map formed by the elements of these traversable collections.

I get "map of traversable collections." That would be a map of lists, for example. By that definition alone, a `Map[Int, List[Int]]` would qualify.

But what is "a map formed by the elements of these traversable collections"? It sounds straightforward, but I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

The example code provided in the documentation is ... well ... shall we say, not applicable?

> ```
> val xs = List(
>            Set(1, 2, 3),
>            Set(1, 2, 3)
>          ).flatten
> // xs == List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
>
> val ys = Set(
>            List(1, 2, 3),
>            List(3, 2, 1)
>          ).flatten
> // ys == Set(1, 2, 3)
> ```

I've tried a few different things, but they yield the same error. Here are a couple of examples:

```
scala> val m = Map(List(1) -> List(1,2,3), List(2) -> List(4,5,6), List(3) -> List(7,8,9))
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[List[Int],List[Int]] = Map(List(1) -> List(1, 2, 3), List(2) -> List(4, 5, 6), List(3) -> List(7, 8, 9))

scala> m.flatten
<console>:9: error: No implicit view available from (List[Int], List[Int]) => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
              m.flatten
                ^

scala> val m = Map(1 -> List(1,2,3), 2 -> List(4,5,6), 4 -> List(7,8,9))
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(1, 2, 3), 2 -> List(4, 5, 6), 4 -> List(7, 8, 9))

scala> m.flatten
<console>:9: error: No implicit view available from (Int, List[Int]) => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
              m.flatten
                ^
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't "know" how to interpret the elements that you store in the map. That is, the interpretation is not evident, so you have to provide your own implicit view of the elements into a traversable. For example, for the case you provide, you want to interpret each element of the map of type `(Int, List[Int])` perhaps into a new list of tuples in which the first element is the original element key and the value is each of the values originally in the given key's value. In code:

```
implicit val flattener = (t: (Int,List[Int])) ⇒ t._2.map(x ⇒ (t._1, x))

val m = Map(1 → List(1, 2, 3), 2 → List(4, 5), 3 → List(6))
val fm = m.flatten
```

But you have to provide the "flattening" function yourself.